# Keyboard customisation in React-Native / Expo project

Tags: typescript, react-native, expo, keyboard, customization

I'm currently working on a project where i have been asked to customize the keyboard styling so that it matches the overall design. i'm working with React-Native which is being managed by Expo.

I have searched online for answers but i found practically nothing. It is either deprecated or just will not work. Some say it is possible and others say it is not.

Thanks in advance!